# Question about "could you please not do sth"

Tags: grammar

I'm an ESL student, and I just don't understand how to answer this kind of question. for example, If I ask someone, "Could you please not open the window?",
and he answers, "No, I won't do that"

Does it mean that he will not open the window or he will open the window?
I am confused about the "that" in his answer represents the "not open the window" or "open the window"?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether he's intentionally being obtuse and unhelpful or not. If he's a normal person just acceding to your request, he means he won't open the window. But the proper answer to the question is, "Sure, I won't open it."

A person who is being a PITA will mean "No, I won't NOT open the window," which means he will open the window.

Answer (score 0):

“Please do something. “ Is a request.
“Do something”. Is an order.
“If it pleases you, do something.” Is a less ambiguous way to request 
“Please do something.” Causes a problem because one of the parties may differ on whether it is directive or not. The situation gets exploitative  when someone thinks they have been ordered, while the other person knows darn well that it was technically a request.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to address the given question? OP is asking about "could you please _not_ do something?" and what a "negative" response means.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a question, even though it has the form of a question.  The "please" makes it a request.  The appropriate response is to comply by not opening the window or to refuse to comply by opening it, as appropriate to the situation.

Comment: This is not what he is asking. He is the one asking someone to not open the window, and he is confused about the other guy's response.

Comment: @ZerGreenOne, I disagree.  Besides, no answer from anyone would be appropraite, because *it's not a question*.

Comment: Quote: I am confused about the "that" **in his answer** represents the "not open the window" or "open the window" **[in my question (implicit)]**

Comment: @ZerGreenOne, But there is no answer, since it is not a question, so **his answer** is not interpretable.  No question, no answer.

Comment: You can still answer things that aren't questions. You can answer a call. You can answer a request. If you google "define answer", you find that answer means "a thing that is said, written, or done as a reaction to a question, statement, or situation". So it basically just needs to be a reaction to something. And it gives you plenty of examples of answers to things that aren't questions. Is English even your first language?

Comment: Sorry, I think I get angry a little too easily.

Comment: @ZerGreenOne, Yes, you can answer a call.  But no, you can't answer a request, although you can respond to one.  This is as close as I can come: She asked her husband would he please turn out the light, and her husband answered yes.  Maybe that's okay.  But all this concerns the wording of the original question, but not the question itself.  There is no ambiguity -- his response "no, I won't do that" is a refusal of the request, regardless of whether you can call it an "answer".

Comment: @GregLee If I ask my classmate, "Could you please not report my mistake to the head teacher?" and he answers, "No, I won't do that". Is that means he will not report me to the head teacher?

Comment: It means he accedes to my request -- he will not report me.  (Without the word "please" in there, there is a legalistic interpretation as a question, not a request, meaning: would it be physically possible to avoid reporting me.)

Comment: A request is implicitly a question, so it can be answered. When you **ask** someone to do something, you are implicitly asking a question, like, can you do this for me? Although admittedly it might also be possible to tell someone to do something, which isn't really a request, but it is related.